# Facebook not showing og:image thumbnail in MSIE9 on subsequent shares

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer-9

I'm having a bizarre problem with Facebook. When I share my content in MSIE 9, it successfully loads the thumbnail the first time I share a URL, but if I share it again, the thumbnail does not load (and never loads again). It just shows their animated "loading" image for several seconds, then that disappears and so do the thumbnail options.

You can see this yourself by clicking these Facebook share links in MSIE 9.

[Example 1](http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%253A%252F%252Fsparkengine.call2action.com%252Fsparks%252F5186%252Flive)
[Example 2](http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%253A%252F%252Fsparkengine.call2action.com%252Fsparks%252F5175%252Flive)

The same sharing functionality works fine in other browsers, and sharing other pages (e.g. Youtube videos) from the same MSIE 9 works fine every time.

Running [Facebook's debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) does not resolve the problem, nor does it report any problems with the OpenGraph tags on my page. It even shows the thumbnails in question.

Looking at the Network tab of the Developer Tools in Facebook shows that the thumbnail image is being loaded each time I share the content.

**Update**

I've found that MSIE 9 will display the image under the following conditions:
- if I have the image in my cache already
- if the browser doesn't make a request to the server to the safe_image.php URL where the image comes from.

I've been messing around with this test page: http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://c2a-v3-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/sparks%2Fspark_5079%2Findex_test.html

I cannot load the image if I refresh the page, as that makes a request to the server for safe_image.php. It doesn't matter whether the response is a 200 or a 304, the image does not display. However, if I then go to the location bar and press enter, that's a "navigate" event instead of a "refresh", no request is made for the image, and it is displayed (after being loaded from the cache).

I've tried serving the image from another domain, adding the og:image:secure_url tag, having Facebook crawl the HTML on a different domain, and this is the best I can do so far. Unfortunately, it's pretty useless because it means the first share from any user will never work right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved! Bizarrely enough, the issue was the dimensions of the image. If I reduce the dimensions of the og:image to fit in a 255x255 pixel box, the sharing works perfectly in MSIE9! Slightly larger sizes, like 262x262, do not work.

I had to run the URL through the Facebook debug tool to clear our their cache of it, of course.

Comment: **+1** Excellent Answer! Now that you nailed this issue, perhaps the `255x255` size is maximum when image dimensions are ***not*** provided. The docs at [**Open Graph Protocol**](http://ogp.me#structured) website suggests that you can define ***image*** `width`, `height`, and MIMI `type`. If so, this might allow *larger images* to be seen in IE9 without requiring to resize the thumbnails?

Comment: I was actually providing the sizes and MIME type when testing the different sizes. The larger images didn't work consistently under any circumstances that I tried.

Answer (score 2):

the sharer function of fb is no longer supported by facebook
you should use the feed dialog part of javascript api: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

also make sure your og meta tags contain the correct information http://ogp.me/ that could be your problem, the image size is a meta tag and the image should be 200x200 at least to optimize the scraping of the og meta data

you can also check what errors the meta data is getting from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: do you have a source on the "sharer function no longer supported? Also, as I said in my question, the image is showing up correctly in the Facebook debug tool, and it does not report any errors at all.

Comment: **+1** Great answer. FYI: As you wrote the minimum **`200x200`** should be used, the OP discovered the solution was to limit the size to maximum of **`255x255`**. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I have another answer to your Question.

Reference: [**https://sparkengine.call2action.com/sparks/5186/live**](https://sparkengine.call2action.com/sparks/5186/live)

The above webpage you want to share doesn't have the **Facebook Opengraph** protocol for the webpage's thumbnail to be used when sharing links with Facebook.

Here's what that metatag should look like:

```css
<meta property="og:image" content="https://sparkengine.call2action.com/assets/c2a_logo_white-6396a6a536d065359780af683e66dd2a.png"/>
```

Read more about using this propery name [**HERE**](http://www.bravr.com/custom-thumbnail-facebook-shares/).

In **Facebook's debugger** tool, it could just be showing a thumbnail that's rendered in the debugger but not necessarily associated with the shared link process.

Although you do see ***a thumbnail image*** in the Network Tab, it's not necessarily the case that this will be used in the shared link process, hence the **Facebook Opengraph** protocol solves this problem, and allows further customization.

---

**EDIT:**
It appears at the moment of this writing, your webpage's template has changed. I now notice that the only previously seen og metatag names of:

```
og:video
og:video:height
og:video:width
```

now includes the `og:image` metatag, along with other newly added `og` metatag properties.

Current image file provided for `og:image` metatag:

[**https://c2a-v3.s3.amazonaws.com/sparks/spark_5186/media/thumbnails/spark_5186_09_28_2012_WgZN50Q.jpg**](https://c2a-v3.s3.amazonaws.com/sparks/spark_5186/media/thumbnails/spark_5186_09_28_2012_WgZN50Q.jpg)

In Firefox web browser, but not in IE8, accessing the og:image directly in the browsers address bar produced this download box:

[image]

What also struck me odd about that download is that it's identified as a **flash movie**. To be sure, no issues were seen in IE8.

I then tested that image thumbnail link directly in Chromes web browser, and that caused an automatic download of that image, but it did not display in the browser, treating it like a downloaded mime type file.

This was true for both thumbnails in both your examples. Perhaps the server-side **flash-to-thumbnail** is saving the images with incorrect mime file-type information. Once downloaded and analyzed in **IfranView**, no errors were reported with the `.jpg image`, as IrfanView will check the file header to ensure it matches it's file-type extension automatically. I would look into how these thumbnails are created on the back-end.

---

**DIGGING DEEPER:**

I now understand that you'll have no control on how these thumbnails are made, since it's a service/process done by **Amazon s3 Web Servers**.

Digging deeper, I see that the main domain for this image files URL is for an `XML File`:

Reference: [**https://c2a-v3.s3.amazonaws.com**](https://c2a-v3.s3.amazonaws.com)

Google to the rescue. I typed in [**amazon thumbnail opens as file**](http://bit.ly/12omsmE) and [**this article**](http://ansonalex.com/troubleshooting/fix-articles-linked-on-facebook-dont-display-thumbnails-images/) mentioned to drop the protocol `http://www.` or `https://www.` when using a URL for `og` metatags.

The [**Facebook Debugger**](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=sparkengine.call2action.com%2Fsparks%2F5186%2Flive) shows no errors when dropping the `https://` too, even though it will be report as `http://` protocol.

**Try:**

```html
<meta content='sparkengine.call2action.com/sparks/5186/live' property='og:url'>
<meta content='c2a-v3.s3.amazonaws.com/sparks%2Fspark_5186%2Fmedia%2Fthumbnails%2Fspark_5186_09_28_2012_WgZN50Q.jpg' property='og:image'>
```

Note any Facebook user can force **HTTPS** requests via there settings, otherwise **HTTP** is assumed here.

**Resulting Shared Link Generated:**

```html
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fsparkengine.call2action.com%2Fsparks%2F5186%2Flive
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed investigation, @arttronics! I've (sort of) made some of the changes you've suggested, replacing some of my https URLs with http. I don't like the idea of dropping the protocol from the URLs altogether. The net effect has been to get the thumbnails working sometimes, but not always. It works maybe one in five tries. This is better than before, but still pretty bad :-(

Comment: I also tried updating the MIME type of some of the images in question on S3. That doesn't seem to make a difference in the behavior of the thumbnail loading.

Comment: Perhaps there are other settings in your Amazon S3 product that can fix this issue. The only other suggestion is to use another image server (imageshack.us public hosting just to test idea) to verify that this bug goes away, which brings you closer to a solution. If that is the case, it's then a good idea to provide an update in your question and enhance it's SO Tags related to Amazon S3 and Facebook Thumbnail solution.